# Ductility of Fe-Ni Alloy

Tags: materials, heat-treatment

Cold worked Fe-Ni rod is very brittle and not suitable for drawing. What would be the best heat treatment parameters for increasing the ductility of a Fe-Ni Alloy? Does increase in the Co content make it brittle? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the total mutual solubility , Ni -Fe alloys are more ductile than about any other ferrous combination. Like any metal , if heavily cold worked ,ductility is reduced. If carbon is added, ductility can be drastically reduced . Generally Ni-Fe alloys are used for unique magnetic properties. Not much else can be said without more information.